# ListView v/s an inflated view added on another view

Tags: android, listview

Suppose i want to make a view like as given below image

Is it efficient to have a custom list-view for this or a simple linear layout with elements which can be inflated and added to another layout. I do not want to have any click operation over the items, i just need to show them over a screen. Which one will be better approach?

I already know how to make Custom ListViews

[image]

Comment: It is better to have as listview. It will be more performant if the items increase in future due to list view recycling

Comment: If the number of items is going to remain the same and small like given example then `LinearLayout` is fine. Otherwise, `ListView` is easier to create and manage. If you use `LinearLayout`, keep in mind that it is advisable to not create too many layouts within layouts, see this: [Optimizing Layout Hierarchy](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)

Comment: as @MadhurAhuja says, the purpose of listview is to handle lists and it is very good at that and optimized for that (cell recycling). Whenever you have a list I would advise to use listview.

Comment: As @CodePro_NotYet suggested, If you have a fix number of item may be less than 10, then `LinearLayout`. otherwise for better performance and recycling of the view `ListView` is better option.